# Blazored server localstorage only works with properties of an object, but not with fields?

Tags: server, blazor

I instantiated an object from the following class and shoved that into a Blazored server localstorage element.

```
public class StatusData{public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty; }
```

When I changed the string property to a field, my Blazor app ran, but the app could not retrieve the localstorage object. I do not know if the object was put into localstorage, or if the retriever did not work.

```
public class StatusData { public string Message = string.Empty; }
```

I added the `{ get; set; }` back in and the localstorage worked again.

I expected that using `Message` as a field or a property would have worked the same.

Can someone help me understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This library uses `System.Text.Json` as its default Json library, and that has a default of ignoring fields.

You can configure it to include fields though.

In your startup/program file you need to configure the `JsonSerializerOptions`

```cs
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage(config =>
        config.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true
    );
```

[README](https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage#configuring-json-serializer-options)

Comment: Correct, but not advisable. Using (only) properties gives you much more control over use of you classes. Lessons were learned from BinaryFormatter.